# How do Google Analytics non-interaction events effect Active User counts?

Tags: google-analytics, analytics

I wanted a more complete idea of how people are using my app, so I've added the following function to it, which fires every 60 seconds:

```
function gaHeartbeat() {
    ga('send', {
        hitType: 'event',
        eventCategory: 'heartbeat',
        eventAction: '1min',
        nonInteraction: true,
    });
}
```

And the events are coming in. My question is - Do these events keep users on the "Active Users" count within the real-time reporting? If someone has sent only these `nonInteraction` events for the last 60 minutes, will they still count towards the number of users currently on my site?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Users that send only non-interaction (NI) hits will not show up in the Active Users real-time report, however, if you click on the `Events (Last 30 minutes)` report, you will still see all interaction and non-interaction events within the last 30 minutes. Other than affecting bounce rate and time on site metrics, NI events are considered as normal (ie. as interactive) for other metrics so those users would still count towards the total number of users on your site.